Calculate availability percentage in Kibana and show as graph
See part of results  of our lodging index. We have 1000 + lodgings in our index and each lodging has own _id.  The availability data set shows available_on days. If a day is NOT available_on then the date is remove from the available_on data set. Also days in de past are not present anymore in de dataset.  I want to great pie chart in kibana where we show the percentage of availability in the future.  (date.now - 31 december 2024) = X days dived by how many days left in availabity set.  Is this possible in kibana ?
 {
      "_index": "lodgings_production_20240229101400636",
      "_id": "9778",
      "_version": 2608,
      "_score": 0,
      "_routing": "9778",
      "_source": {
        "id": 9778,
        "street": "Blommeke 7",
        "city": null,
        "zip": null,
        "state": null,
        "beds": 4,
        "baths": 4,
        "sq__ft": null,
        "sale_date": null,
        "price": 450,
        "latitude": 51.1222888533331,
        "longitude": 3.31087592505669,
        "created_at": "2024-04-05T00:00:00.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-04-11T13:50:58.982Z",
        "lodging_type": "bnb",
        "adults": 8,
        "children": 0,
        "infants": null,
        "owner_id": 1410,
        "region_id": 102,
        "name": "Equilodge",
        "label": "None",
        "title": null,
        "subtitle": null,
        "description": "<p>Equilodge is een <strong>luxe vakantiehuis</strong> gelegen op een prachtig <strong>2,5 ha groot landgoed</strong>. Het huis is <strong>modern ingericht</strong> met <strong>stijlvolle ruimtes</strong> binnen en buiten. Hier te <strong>midden van de natuur </strong>geniet u van rust en privacy. Het is een ideale plek voor families of vrienden die willen genieten van het buitenleven en specifiek voor <strong>paardeneigenaren&nbsp;</strong>want u kunt uw eigen paard meenemen en naast het huis stallen gedurende uw verblijf. Als u geen eigen paarden meebrengt, zullen er geen paarden aanwezig zijn op het terrein.</p>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>Indeling Equilodge | 250m2 | 8 personen</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li>Ruime keuken met een eettafel en een keukeneiland met een (ontbijt)bar&nbsp;</li>\r\n\t<li>De keuken is voorzien van o.a. een koelkast, vriezer, vaatwasser, oven, magnetron, toaster, blender en espressomachine</li>\r\n\t<li>Ruime woonkamer met comfortabele banken, televisie en een open haard.</li>\r\n\t<li>Vier ruime slaapkamers, twee met een king-size bed (200x180cm) en twee met twee enkele bedden (200x90cm), elk met schuifdeuren die toegang bieden tot de tuin</li>\r\n\t<li>Alle slaapkamers hebben een ensuite badkamer met een douche, wastafel en toilet. Een van de badkamers heeft tevens een ligbad.&nbsp;</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>Buiten:</strong><br />\r\nHet huis wordt omringd door een <strong>grote bostuin met een vijver </strong>en rondom velden waar paarden kunnen grazen. Tussen de keuken en de woonkamer ligt een overdekt terras met een <strong>ingebouwde barbecue</strong> en grote eettafel. De tuin is volledig afgezet en er zijn priv&eacute; parkeerplaatsen.</p>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>Highlights:</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li>Equilodge is een <strong>perfect verblijf voor paardeneigenaren</strong>. Wilt u uw paard meenemen? Dat kan. U kunt uw paard tegen betaling stallen bij het huis. Vanaf het huis starten diverse ruiterpaden.</li>\r\n\t<li>Equilodge is een <strong>ecologisch en vrijwel energie-neutraal vakantieverblijf&nbsp;</strong>met diverse milieuvriendelijke voorzieningen&nbsp;</li>\r\n\t<li>Het huis is uitgerust met centrale verwarming, een automatisch koelsysteem, ge&iuml;ntegreerd muzieksysteem, smart televisie en wifi-internet</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
        "meta_desc": "Equilodge | Een uitstapje in de natuur met alle moderne comfort, een prachtige bostuin voor de deur en eigen paardenstallen. Contact Nice2stay voor uw vakantie in België.\r\n",
        "meta_title": "Equilodge | Nice2stay | Stijlvol huis op een prachtig landgoed nabij Brugge ",
        "slug": "equilodge",
        "h1": "Equilodge | Eco-lodge te midden van de natuur op het Belgische platteland",
        "h2": "Modern huis voor 8p met prachtige grote tuinen vlakbij Brugge",
        "h3": "Een heerlijke plek voor een weekendje weg in de natuur",
        "highlight_1": "Modern design",
        "highlight_2": "Idyllische setting",
        "highlight_3": "Ideaal voor paardeneigenaren",
        "summary": "<p><strong>Ondergedompeld in de natuur</strong> op een <strong>idyllisch landgoed</strong> op het Belgische platteland, ligt in alle rust en privacy <strong>Equilodge</strong>. Deze <strong>moderne eco-lodge</strong> combineert &ldquo;the best of two worlds&rdquo; met een <strong>stijlvol design</strong>&nbsp;&eacute;n <strong>milieuvriendelijke voorzieningen</strong> met een&nbsp;minimale impact op zijn schitterende natuurlijke omgeving.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>De woning wordt gekenmerkt door de <strong>grote ramen rondom</strong> die niet alleen zorgen voor veel daglicht maar ook de <strong>grenzen tussen binnen en buiten geheel wegnemen.</strong> De inrichting is <strong>minimalistisch&nbsp;en stijlvol</strong> met gladde betonvloeren, vele <strong>houten accenten</strong>, hedendaagse meubels en warme aardetinten op de muren. Het huis is zo gebouwd dat het de zon volgt&hellip; de <strong>vier ensuite slaapkamers</strong> liggen aan de kant waar de zon opkomt en in de woonruimtes geniet u van <strong>de zonsondergang</strong>. Tussen de <strong>grote eetkamer met volledig ingerichte keuken</strong> en sfeervolle <strong>woonkamer met open haard</strong> ligt een <strong>beschut terras met buitenbarbecue</strong> om te genieten van al-fresco maaltijden.&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Het huis ligt te midden van een <strong>prachtig 2,5 ha landgoed</strong> met een <strong>mooie bostuin met een vijver</strong> voor de deur en volop ruimte om te rusten en&nbsp;te <strong>spelen</strong>. Niet alleen staat de <strong>natuur centraal</strong> in Equilodge, maar ook <strong>paarden</strong>. Equilodge biedt de mogelijkheid om uw <strong>eigen paard mee te nemen en te stallen naast het huis (anders zullen de stallen leeg zijn)</strong>;&nbsp;ruiterpaden starten direct voor het deur zodat u kunt genieten van een heerlijk weekend weg samen.&nbsp;Ook <strong>wandelend en fietsend</strong> kunt het omliggende platteland ontdekken, met het <strong>Natuurpark Bulskampveld</strong>&nbsp;op slechts enkele kilometers afstand. Als u de omgeving verder wilt verkennen, ga dan naar de prachtige <strong>historische stad Brugge</strong>, Gent of breng een bezoek aan de <strong>Belgische kust in Knokke</strong> met zijn prachtige stranden.&nbsp;</p>\r\n",
        "short_desc": "",
        "location_description": "<p>Equilodge ligt in alle rust op het Belgische platteland, aan de rand van het charmante dorp <strong>Beernem</strong> in West-Vlaanderen. De omgeving is&nbsp;bezaaid met leuke dorpjes, weelderig groen en kronkelende rivieren en biedt een rustige ontsnapping aan de drukte van het stadsleven. Beernem voorziet u in al uw dagelijkse voorzieningen en langs het<strong> kanaal </strong>kunt u uitstekend wandelen en fietsen of u kunt met een <strong>kajak</strong> het kanaal ontdekken. Het <strong>natuurpark Bulskampveld</strong>&nbsp;ligt direct voor de deur om te wandelen en fietsen, en voor kinderen vindt u hier een houten speeltuin. Voor diegenen die hun eigen paard meenemen, starten vanuit het huis ruiterroutes dus u kunt meteen de paden op.&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Op slechts een klein eindje rijden vindt u de <strong>betoverende stad Brugge</strong> (17 km), ook wel het &#39;Veneti&euml; van het Noorden&#39; genoemd. Hier kunt u door geplaveide straatjes slenteren, de middeleeuwse architectuur bewonderen en een boottocht maken langs de pittoreske grachten. Mis de kans niet om het beroemde Belfort van Brugge te bezoeken, met een panoramisch uitzicht over de stad beneden. Op korte afstand van Brugge ligt de&nbsp;stad <strong>Gent</strong> (36 km), bekend om zijn prachtige gotische architectuur, kunstsc&egrave;ne en levendige sfeer. Verken het historische Gravensteen, dwaal over de bruisende marktpleinen en dompel uzelf onder in de rijke geschiedenis en cultuur van deze fascinerende stad. Aan de Belgische kust lonkt&nbsp;de <strong>badplaats Knokke</strong> (35 km), bekend om zijn prachtige stranden, luxe winkels en bruisende nachtleven. Ontspan op de zandstranden, slenter over de bruisende boulevard en geniet van heerlijke visgerechten in een van de vele restaurants van de stad.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Mocht u willen rusten in de natuur, op zoek zijn naar een actief weekendje weg of een prachtige plek voor&nbsp;uitstapjes naar Brugge en de kust, de Equilodge vormt de&nbsp;ideale thuisbasis.&nbsp;Komt u met het vliegtuig is dan ligt het vliegveld van Brussel op 93 km afstand (1u10min).</p>\r\n",
        "location": {
          "lat": 51.1222888533331,
          "lon": 3.31087592505669
        },
        "country_id": 242,
        "country": [
          "belgie",
          "belgium"
        ],
        "region": [
          "west-vlaanderen",
          "west-flanders"
        ],
        "extended_name": "Equilodge - bnb - België West-Vlaanderen",
        "available_on": [
          "2024-04-16",
          "2024-04-17",
          "2024-04-18",
          "2024-04-19",
          "2024-04-21",
          "2024-04-22",
          "2024-04-23"
        ]
    "availability_price": [
          500,
          500,
          500,
          500,
          500,
          500,
          500,
          500,
          500
        ]

